# How do I generate sql/civicrm_generated.mysql using bin/regen.sh file?

Tags: sql, debugging

I am working on CRM-11369 bug. However, I was facing problems in generating sql/civicrm_generated.mysql using bin/regen.sh file. The fifth line of bin/regen.sh file is 'source dirname $0/setup.conf'. But there is no setup.conf file in this folder. So I made a copy of bin/setup.conf.txt as bin/setup.conf and filled in the values for CIVISOURCEDIR, DBNAME, DBUSER and DBPASS. I'm still runnning into errors.

I get the following error:

bower *angular-jquery-dialog-service#civicrm resolve https://github.com/totten/angular-jquery-dialog-service.git#civicrm*

bower *retry Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular failed with ECONNRESET, retrying in 1.0s*

It would be great if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cp bin/setup.conf.txt bin/setup.conf
```

Then edit and fill in appropriate values in the setup.conf file before trying to run regen.sh.